# Incoming Telegram message listener with Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'd like to listen for a new incoming message in a Telegram channel.

I'm using the Telethon package and tried to run the example found in the docs.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = "..."
api_hash = "..."
CHANNEL_ID = "..."

client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=CHANNEL_ID, outgoing=False))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event)

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

This code runs, asks me for my phone number and the login code. But after that, nothing happens.
When a message is sent to the channel, I don't see anything printed out.

Comment: Are you sure the client you authorized is in the channel? Are you sure the `CHANNEL_ID` is correct? (IDs should be integer numbers, **not** string). Generally it's better to try things without restricting much (no `chats=` filter, no `outgoing`) to confirm your values before using them.

Comment: Yes, I'm subscribed to the channel and the id is correct. I tried with the channel name also, same result

Comment: You might be affected by https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/3936. Unfortunately I am not able to reproduce your (or this linked) issue.

Comment: @Lonami Thanks IDs should be integer numbers, not string) this was important for me